# Android RelativeLayout alignCenter from another View

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with two children that are also both `RelativeLayout`s containing a few buttons and things. These children layouts are not centered in my main layout, and the main layout does contain some other things off the the sides of these two. I want the first one to be on top of the second one. That is easy enough, just use `android:layout_below="@+id/firstLayout"` in the second one. But I also want the second one to be aligned on the center of the first one. By that I mean I want the second layout to find the center of the first one, and align itself so that its center is in the same x position. I see `alignLeft, alignRight, alignTop, and alignBaseline`, but no center. Is this possible to do without having to hard code a margin to scoot the second layout over some?

Here is a rough example of what I am trying to end up with, the blue bar would be the first layout, and the red box would be the second layout. I know that I could wrap them both in another `RelativeLayout` that has sizes equal to `"wrap_content"` and then use `centerHorizontal="true"` for the second one. But I would really rather leave both as children of my main layout (I would have to make some changes to the way certain parts of my app work if I make them children of a separate layout. Which I am trying to avoid.)

[image: Example of what I want]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can set width of parent layout to "wrap_content" you could then put both children layouts to center

Comment: I think you mean width. But this approach won't work because there are other things inside the parent layout. And these two children are actually off to one side of the parent.

Comment: Yes, I ment width. Maybe you could put one more layout with align left and right of first relative layout (blue square) and than put red square inside it in center

Comment: That might work actually. I know for the java portion of my app to work as it is now I need the blue bar layout to stay inside the main layout parent. But I think I won't have to make any changes if I put just the red one inside a new parent.

Comment: So you got me thinking about it. I don't even think I need to use an extra parent layout. I can use use the alignLeft and alignRight on the bottom layout, so that it is the same width as the top, and then use gravity="centerHorizontal" on it

Comment: Yes, but it depends on views that are inside

Comment: Aligning one view to opposite sides of the other view works great for centering.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you can set `alignLeft` and `alignRight` to the desired view and then use gravity on the element you want centered.

For example:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_aligntRight="@+id/firstLayout"
android:gravity="center"
```

If the component is not a `TextView` (or a view where you don't need the background) you could then wrap it in a `FrameLayout` with the above properties.

```
<MyView id="@+id/firstLayout" .. other props/>

<FrameLayout 
    ... other props
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_aligntRight="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <MyView id="@+id/myAlignedView" ..other props />

</FrameLayout>
```

This way, the bottom view will be a Frame with the same width as the upper one, but inside it there will be a view that is centered to the width.

Of course this only works when you know which is the larger view. If not, as Laranjeiro answered, wrap both contents in another layout with centered gravity.

Answer (score 4):

For texts I have been using this f.e for a vertical-center alignment:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/theBigOne"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/theBigOne"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/theBigOne"
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! You can set alignTop and alignBottom to the view you'd like and it'll vertically center it against that view.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked to me was wrap both components in a FrameLayout with the dimension of the bigger component and set the second component in the center of the FrameLayout using the property

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red_component"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_component"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just set like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomHolder"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Read the question: "These children layouts are not centered in my main layout".